# Azure Reporting - Report Viewer running in multiple instances does not show all images

Tags: azure, reporting, reportviewer

I am using a asp.net webrole project with a report viewer in Azure Reporting.
At the beginning I faced some problems with 'ASP.NET session has expired' which I solved setting AsyncRendering to false and setting
sessionState timeout ="120" mode="InProc" cookieless="true" in web.config.
However when I deploy the project runnign in a single instance everything is working fine.
But when I deploy the project in mulitiple (two) instances some images (graphs, gauges etc.) are not loaded. However if i right click on the missing image I am able to load the image via context menu.
Any ideas ? seems to be some timimg problem for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you are using InProc session state. You can't control the load balancer, so it's possible that you're loading the page from one instance, but the images from an other instance. This means that your session will be different on both instances.

When working with more than one instance you shouldn't store your session InProc, but choose a distirbuted storage (like table storage, SQL Azure or AppFabric Cache). This will allow all of your instances to use the same session data.

Example: [Session State Provider for Windows Azure Caching](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg185668.aspx)